# Find next record in Dictionary/List

Tags: c#

Hey all I have a little problem with a script i have made in C#

In this script attached below, I collect loot from an object and this script displays it. Now for example if i want to insert item [0] into inventory and item [1] when those items are different then the script overwrites that slot in the inventory. What i need to do is a way of checking if that slot is full or matches the item currently in the slot. Ive tried +1 ++ += on the [] but it doesn't work. Please help :) Thanks in advance

```
     // First Item
    if (GUILayout.Button(lootDictionary[0], GUILayout.Height(50)))
    {
        if (lootDictionary[0] != string.Empty && binlootamounts[0] != 0)
        {
            Inventory.inventoryDictionary[0] = lootDictionary[0];
            if (binlootamounts[0] != 0)
            {
                binlootamounts[0] -= 1;
                Inventory.dictionaryAmounts[0] += 1;
            }
        }
        if (binlootamounts[0] == 0)
        {
          lootDictionary[0] = string.Empty; 
        }

    }
    GUILayout.Label(binlootamounts[0].ToString(), GUILayout.Height(50));
    //Second Item
    if (GUILayout.Button(lootDictionary[1], GUILayout.Height(50)))
    {
        if (lootDictionary[1] != string.Empty && binlootamounts[1] != 0)
        {
            Inventory.inventoryDictionary[1] = lootDictionary[1];
            if (binlootamounts[1] != 0)
            {
                binlootamounts[1] -= 1;
                Inventory.dictionaryAmounts[1] += 1;
            }
        }
        if (binlootamounts[1] == 0)
        {
          lootDictionary[1] = string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I wish we all could collect loot from `Object` instances.

Comment: this does collect and populate efficiently just unsure how to get it to move onto the next slot, you think i will need another method or calculation somewhere? i could just have certain items for certain slots but its unrealistic thank you for replying :)

Comment: what is your loot dictionary made of? what kind of objects go inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very general, and might be off the track, but without more details, it's hard to say.

I'd say make sure your dictionary implements an interface that knwos how to compare it's objects, and then make sure your loot objects inherit from it.

A quick example would be something like the following (mind you, I didn't try to actually implement everything and make sure it works, because I have no idea what you're working with, but it'll give you a direction) :

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int,IMyLoot> MyLootDict = new Dictionary<int,IMyLoot>();
}

interface IMyLoot
{
    Loot GetLoot();
    // maybe you need something like this?
    bool CompareToOtherLoot();
}

class Loot {
    public int GoldValue { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}


class Weapon : Loot, IMyLoot {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Loot GetLoot() {return this;}

    public bool CompareToOtherLoot() {
        // Figure out how you compare to other loot
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with i implemented this with a few mods and it worked! :)

Comment: Glad I could have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a generic collection that supports both fast access (O(logN) or better) and counting of duplicates, you can create something like the following `CountedSet<T>`:

```
public class CountedSet<T> : ICollection<T> 
{
    readonly IEqualityComparer<T> comparer;
    readonly Dictionary<T, int> dictionary;
    int totalCount = 0;
    int version = 1;

    public CountedSet(IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (comparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
        if (collection == null)
            collection = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        this.comparer = comparer;
        int capacity;
        var coll = collection as ICollection<T>;
        if (coll != null)
            capacity = coll.Count;
        else
            capacity = 0;
        dictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>(capacity, comparer);
        totalCount = 0;
        foreach (var item in collection)
            Add(item);
    }

    public CountedSet(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : this(collection, EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }

    public CountedSet()
        : this(Enumerable.Empty<T>())
    {
    }

    int ComputeTotalCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            count += pair.Value;
        return count;
    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    void AssertValid()
    {
        Debug.Assert(totalCount >= 0, "totalCount >= 0");
        Debug.Assert(totalCount == ComputeTotalCount());
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            Debug.Assert(pair.Value > 0, "pair.Value > 0");
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        foreach (var item in other)
            Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> other) 
    {
        foreach (var item in other)
            Remove(item);
    }

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        int itemCount;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out itemCount))
        {
            Debug.Assert(itemCount > 0, "itemCount > 0");
            dictionary[item] = itemCount + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary[item] = 1;
        }
        version++;
        totalCount++;
        AssertValid();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        dictionary.Clear();
        totalCount = 0;
        version++;
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            array[arrayIndex++] = item;
    }

    public int CountItem(T item)
    {
        int count;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out count))
            return count;
        return 0;
    }

    public int Count { get { return totalCount; } }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        int itemCount;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(item, out itemCount))
        {
            Debug.Assert(itemCount > 0, "itemCount > 0");
            itemCount--;
            if (itemCount < 1)
                dictionary.Remove(item);
            else
                dictionary[item] = itemCount;
            totalCount--;
            version++;
            AssertValid();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int initialVersion = this.version;
        foreach (var pair in this.dictionary)
            for (int i = 0; i < pair.Value; i++)
            {
                if (initialVersion != this.version)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("collection was modified");
                }
                yield return pair.Key;
            }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

More generally, if you are going to maintain an in-memory database of quantities of objects of some type, you need to think about your requirements for maintaining them:

1. Do you need persistent identifiers for each quantity of items -- e.g. inventory slot numbers?
2. How do the persistent numbers change as items are added and removed?  Do they adjust upwards and downwards to maintain a continuous range, or can there be gaps?
3. Do all objects of the same type merge when added to the inventory, or do some not merge?  E.g. gold merges, but named artifacts may not.
4. Are there limits on the total quantity of objects?

Whatever you decide, you can take the approach above, encapsulating one or more standard .Net collections into a single wrapper collection that maintains both quick access to, and proper accounting for, your data.